# Is there a way to auto approve Pull Request?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I am using Azure DevOps Repo and Build Pipeline and creating Pull Request using Rest API and trying approving it via Rest API by setting vote = 10 but getting below error.

**You cannot record a vote for someone else**

Is there a way to automate this process.

Comment: If you're automating approving a PR, why create a PR at all?

Comment: @rickvdbosch because we have policy on master branch and need to auto approve PR for specific changes.

Comment: If you need to bypass the normal rules of PRs and reviews and checks and approvals, then it might be easier to grant yourself the [Bypass Branch Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#bypass-branch-policies) permissions.

Comment: Auto approved PR are useful to making sure all tests passed whist implementing Trunk-Based Development. You can read more about this technique in DORA: https://dora.dev/devops-capabilities/technical/trunk-based-development/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pull request status [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops#pull-request-status) will be helpful in auto approving the pull request.
also check the [Status API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20statuses) to add custom status to your pull request.
Below is the sample pull request status code.

```
{
    "state": "succeeded",
    "description": "CI build succeeded",
    "context": {
        "name": "my-ci-system",
        "genre": "continuous-integration"
    },
    "targetUrl": "http://contoso.com/CI/builds/1"
}
```

Here is the related [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56760528) threads for pull requests